# Karp-reduction of Disk Covering Problem

Tags: reductions, logic

While preparing for final exam, I encountered a (target) problem where you have $M$ lines and $L$ points and you want to answer if it's possible to cover them all using $K$ disks of unit radius (decision problem).

I would like to reduce the [Disk Covering Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_covering_problem) to the problem at hand to show that the problem is NP-hard. Is my logic valid if I construct an instance of the target problem with no lines, meaning to set $M=0$, and reduce an arbitrary instance of the disk covering problem to it? or does setting $M=0$ invalidate the reduction?

Comment: Can you define Disk Covering Problem you want to reduce from (which needs to be NP-Hard)? What are the instances of this problem? What are the yes-instances or the measure you want to optimize (which should depend on the instance)?